# namespaced controllers + models in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a namespace for my product related controllers under products...

```
  scope :module => :products do
    resources :products
    resources :product_images
  end
```

which worked great.

independently, i had added an autoload path so i could put models into subdirectories.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

which also worked great.

when i try to use both together..., i receive errors.

```
Expected /app/models/products/product.rb to define Products::Product
```

even though i should not have to namespace my model, for the sake of troubleshooting, if i DO namespace my model... the error becomes...

```
Expected /app/models/products/product.rb to define Product
```

is there additional configuration i need for these two to work together?

Comment: Have you tried removing the path config and using the namespaced model?

Comment: yeah that seems to work, but i would really like to avoid namespacing my models.

Comment: am i required to namespace my models if i namespace the associated controllers?  that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 9):

Just rename: `/app/models/products/` to something like `/app/models/products_related/`.

If the subfolder is a model's name, Rails assumes the files inside derive from it.

Comment: I had this exact problem (in a rails 2.2.2 app) and this worked for me.  Thanks!